# Automatically strip trailing whitespace when fetching data with `DBI::dbGetQuery()` in R?

Tags: r, dbi, trailing

I work with a database (of which I am not the DBA) that has character columns of length greater than the actual data.

Is it possible to automatically strip trailing whitespace when fetching data with `DBI::dbGetQuery()`? (i.e. something similar to `utils::read.table(*, strip.white = TRUE)`)

```r
# connect
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

# generate fake data
mytable <- data.frame(x = 1, y = LETTERS[1:3], z = paste(LETTERS[1:3], "   "))
dbWriteTable(con, "mytable", mytable)

# fetch data
(a <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from mytable"))
#   x y     z
# 1 1 A A    
# 2 1 B B    
# 3 1 C C    

# trailing space are kept
sapply(a, nchar)
#      x y z
# [1,] 1 1 5
# [2,] 1 1 5
# [3,] 1 1 5
```

I hope I can avoid something like:

```r
idx <- sapply(a, is.character)
a[idx] <- lapply(a[idx], trimws, which = "left", whitespace = "[ ]")
sapply(a, nchar)
#      x y z
# [1,] 1 1 1
# [2,] 1 1 1
# [3,] 1 1 1
```

If not, is it a good approach?

Comment: you could "trim" the data inside sqllite: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-trim/

Comment: You can define your own function which calls dbGetQuery and then trims each character column so that from then on it is no harder than calling dbGetQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using `select *`, there is nothing SQL is going to do for this. If you select them by-name (which is a "best practice" and in many areas the industry-standard), you can use TRIM:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("select x, y, trim(z) as z from mytable") |>
  str()
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x: num  1 1 1
#  $ y: chr  "A" "B" "C"
#  $ z: chr  "A" "B" "C"
```

There are also `rtrim` and `ltrim` for limiting which side of the string you trim trailing/leading blank space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your proactivity on the r DBI thread in general!

Comment: For the sake of clarity, can you confirm whether there is no nothing included in `DBI::dbGetQuery` (or other DBI function) to do this automatically at fetch-time? (i.e. similarly to `utils::read.table(*, strip.white = TRUE)` for csv data)

Comment: I believe the post-processing of retrieved data is limited (at most) to type/class work, nothing that changes the content of values (such as this).

Comment: There is a mention (in https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/blob/aa38870628766d6e78ce2443cecbbf8c18d87e27/vignettes/DBI-proposal.Rmd#L425) of automatically stripping excessive blanks, but I know of no implementation of that (which was last updated/changed in 2015), and searching the repo reveals nothing for `trim` or `strip`.